# how to set Personalizable attribute to generic list in webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-parts, personalization

I develop web part with custom editor part and faced with this question.
Is it possible in web part set Personalizable attribute to generic List?
For example I want something like this:

```
[WebBrowsable(false)]
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
 public List<AnnouncementItem> Announcements
 {
      get { return _announcements; }
      set { _announcements = value; }
 }
```

Is it possible, and what kind of types at all can be used as "Personalizable"?
Thanks.

**Solution:**
I use a custom EditorPart to select multiple lists using `AssetUrlSelector`, but I need a way to personalize this collection for end user.`List<of custom objects>` doesn't work, but I found that `List<string>` (and only string) work perfectly. So, I get required lists in EditorPart and pass their to the web part using `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a custom EditorPart to add/remove items from the collection. I've never built a web part that personalized a collection so I don't know if it works but I'd definitely try the collection with an EditorPart. If it doesn't work, serialize XML into a string property.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not seem to match your code. Your code shows a collection of custom objects. I doubt an end user will be able to set such a property. To have a property that points to a generic list, you would probably be better off defining the property as a string that contains the URL to a list.